# Abelian category with enough injectives but not functorially

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an Abelian category with enough injectives. Is it always possible to make the injective embedding functorial? By this I mean that there should exist a functor $I \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ and a natural transformation $\operatorname{id} \to I$ such that for all objects $A$, the mapping $A \to I(A)$ is a monomorphism. This should be the same as [this definition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0139) from the Stacks project. (**edit**: in a first version, I was requiring the functor to be additive, which is not what I had in mind even in the case of modules, as pointed out by Jeremy Rickard)

The Stacks project [distinguishes](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0140) categories with enough injectives from categories with functorial injective embeddings, so the two notions should be different. But I realized that I cannot think of an example of a category with enough injectives that does not admit functorial injective embeddings.

**edit** removed a motivation comment that was sparking more discussion than necessary and distracting from the main question.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I agree it probably won't be anything obvious.  I do have a comment about the motivation. Even without functorial injective embeddings, one can choose (assuming a strong form of the axiom of choice) an injective resolution for each object of $\mathcal{A}$. The standard arguments, guarantee the existence of a morphism between chosen injective resolutions lifting a given one, and this is unique up to homotopy. This should give functoriality of derived functors. Aside from a philosophical objection to the first step, I'm not sure I see a problem.

Comment: I agree, but this is a tad unsatisfying and I think it only works for small categories (here, things can depend whether you take classes in NBG or on a Grothendieck universe)

Comment: Plus, I am now actually curious about a possible counterexample

Comment: Isn’t the category of abelian groups a counterexample? What could $I(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ be? There are no nonzero injective abelian groups annihilated by multiplication by $2$.

Comment: Well, it would be $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, right? I don't understand why it would have to be annihilated by $2$. In fact Theorem 19.2.8 in the [stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05NM) constructs a functorial injective embedding for $\operatorname{Mod}_R$.

Comment: But the functor constructed there is not additive, which was one of the conditions you listed.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Of course you are right, I was silly to require the functor to be additive. I am going to edit that out. That said, I am still not sure why $I(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ should be annihilated by $2$. Of course, for all Abelian groups $G$, the image of $\operatorname{Hom}(G, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ inside $\operatorname{Hom}(I(G), I(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}))$ is $2$-torsion. But that image could be strictly contained in the Hom group

Comment: If $I$ were additive then $I(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ would have to be $2$-torsion, since $2.\text{id}_{I(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})}=I(2.\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}})=0$. But sure, if $I$ is not additive then it doesn't need to be.

Comment: As a possible candidate for an abelian category with enough injectives, but without functorial injective emveddings, how about the category of countable abelian groups? This has enough injectives (the injective envelope of a countable group is countable), but  the functor constructed in the Stacks project gives uncountable injectives. But I have no idea how to prove that there is no other suitable functor.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I don't have an idea of any criterion on how to prove that a functorial injective embedding **does not** exist.

Comment: The last comment of this post simply not accurate at all: the lack of functoriality of injective resolution does not prevent derived functors to be functorial at all. Saying that other books simply gloss ove this point is simply not true. For instance, the original book of Cartan and Eilenberg does fully explain functoriality of derived functors, and it has been discussed over and over, uing more and more sophisticated tools.

Comment: And this works with very classical set theory with the axiom of choice (no need at all of universes which were not even available at the birth of homological algebra).

Comment: I ensure you that many books do gloss on this point: I checked them before posting. I did not want to say names. I just checked Cartan-Eilbenberg, and it is indeed more precise. I cite straight from Cartan-Eilenberg "Thus up to natural isomorphism HT(X, Y) is independent of the resolutions X and Y and may be written as (RT)(A, C). These modules together with the maps (RT)(A, C) yield a new (additive) functor RT..." Even here, RT(A, C) is determined up to a (uniquely defined) isomorphism.

Comment: In order to obtain from this an actual functor, you need to choose a resolution for each object. Something that you can do with choice on a small category. On a large category, it seems to me to depend on the foundations that you choose, in particular whether you have choice for classes

Comment: In any case, I wouldn't want this point to distract from the main question, which is about the existence of functorial resolutions - something which is of independent interest

Comment: The axiom of choice also holds for classes in the framework of Bernays and Gödel, which is known to be equivalent to ZFC. I think you should delete the last comment from your question because it is misleading, inaccurate, and as such, does distract from the main question.

Comment: Agreed, I am going to remove the motivation comment

Comment: Welcome back Andrea =]

Comment: @JeremyRickard: I think the following is a functorial injective resolution on countable abelian groups. Let $I(A)$ be the quotient of $\mathbf Q^{(A)}$ by the subgroup (*not* $\mathbf Q$-subspace) generated by $e_{a+b} - e_a - e_b$ for $a,b \in A$. The natural presentation of $A$ as $\mathbf Z^{(A)}$ modulo the same relations gives an injection $A \hookrightarrow I(A)$. Clearly $I(A)$ is divisible and countable, because the same holds for $\mathbf Q^{(A)}$. For example, $I(0) = (\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z)e_0$, and $I(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z) = (\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z)e_0 \oplus (\mathbf Q/2\mathbf Z)e_1$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the dual of an abelian category is also an abelian category, the question is equivalent to the same question for projective resolutions.

I will show that the category $\mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$ of finitely generated abelian groups has enough projectives, but no functorial projective cover. The idea is that multiplication by any $n \in \mathbf Z$ is central in $\mathbf{Ab}$, and we do some representation theory to show that $F(\mathbf Z)$ has to have infinite rank by considering the action of multiplication by $n$ on $\mathbf Z/m$ for all $m$.

First some trivial lemmas:

**Lemma 1.** *The category $\mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$ has enough projectives. For $A \in \mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$, the following are equivalent*

1. *$A$ is projective in $\mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$;*
2. *$A$ is projective in $\mathbf{Ab}$;*
3. *$A$ is finite free.*

*Proof.* Implications (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) and (2) $\Leftrightarrow$ (3) are clear. This immediately gives the first statement. For (1) $\Rightarrow$ (3), choose a surjection $F \twoheadrightarrow A$ with $F$ finite free. By assumption (1) it splits, so $A$ is a summand of a finite free module, hence finite free. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** *Let $F \twoheadrightarrow G$ be an epimorphism of functors $F, G \colon \mathscr C \to \mathscr D$. If $G$ is faithful, then so is $F$.*

*Proof.* Two maps $f, g \colon A \rightrightarrows B$ give a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}F(A) & \twoheadrightarrow & G(A)\\\downdownarrows & & \downdownarrows\\F(B) & \twoheadrightarrow & G(B).\!\end{array}$$
Since the top map is an epimorphism, we see $F(f) = F(g) \Rightarrow G(f) = G(g)$, which by assumption implies $f = g$. $\square$

We are now ready for the main result.

> **Proposition.** *Let $F \colon \mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ be a functor taking every object to a projective object, together with a natural surjection $F \twoheadrightarrow \iota$ onto the inclusion $\iota \colon \mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}} \to \mathbf{Ab}$. Then $F(\mathbf Z)$ has infinite rank. In particular, there is no such functor landing in $\mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$.*

By Lemma 1, this shows that there is no functorial projective hull on $\mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$.

*Proof.* First note that Lemma 2 implies that $F$ is faithful, i.e. for all $A, B \in \mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$, the map
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}(A,B) &\to \operatorname{Hom}(F(A),F(B))\\
f &\mapsto f_*
\end{align*}
is injective. For any $n > 1$, we can equip every $F(A)_{\mathbf Q} = F(A) \otimes_{\mathbf Z} \mathbf Q$ for $A \in \mathbf{Ab}^{\operatorname{f.t.}}$ with the structure of a $\mathbf Q[x]$-module by letting $x$ act by $n_*$, where $n \colon A \to A$ is multiplication by $n$ (so $x^k$ acts by $(n_*)^k = (n^k)_*$ for $k \geq 0$). For any $m$, the natural surjection $\pi \colon \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/m$ gives a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbf Z & \stackrel{n^k}\to & \mathbf Z \\ \!\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptsize \pi_*}\downarrow & & \downarrow{\scriptsize \pi_*}\!\!\!\!\!\! \\ \mathbf Z/m & \underset{n^k}\to & \mathbf Z/m,\!\end{array}$$
which by functoriality gives a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}F(\mathbf Z) & \stackrel{n^k_*}\to & F(\mathbf Z) \\ \!\!\!\!\!\!{\scriptsize \pi_*}\downarrow & & \downarrow{\scriptsize \pi_*}\!\!\!\!\!\! \\ F(\mathbf Z/m) & \underset{n^k_*}\to & F(\mathbf Z/m).\!\end{array}$$
Thus the image of the map $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbf Z,\mathbf Z/m) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Q}(F(\mathbf Z)_{\mathbf Q},F(\mathbf Z/m)_{\mathbf Q})$ is contained in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Q[x]}(F(\mathbf Z)_{\mathbf Q},F(\mathbf Z/m)_{\mathbf Q})$.

If $F(\mathbf Z)$ has finite rank, then $F(\mathbf Z)_\mathbf Q$ has finite length over $\mathbf Q[x]$, hence is supported at finitely many maximal ideals $\mathfrak m \subseteq \mathbf Q[x]$. Since $n$ acts invertibly of order $m$ on $\mathbf Z/(n^m-1)$, the $\mathbf Q[x]$-module $F(\mathbf Z/(n^m-1))_\mathbf Q$ is supported at
$$\mathbf Q[x]\big/\big(x^m-1\big) \cong \prod_{d \mid m} \mathbf Q\big(\zeta_d\big),\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\mathbf Q(\zeta_d)$ is the $d$-th cyclotomic field. Choose $m = p \gg 0$ prime so that $F(\mathbf Z)_\mathbf Q$ is not supported at $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Q[x]}(F(\mathbf Z)_\mathbf Q, F(\mathbf Z/(n^p-1))_\mathbf Q)$ is only supported at $\mathbf Q(\zeta_1) = \mathbf Q[x]/(x-1)$ by (\ref{1}), i.e. the action of $x$ is trivial. But this contradicts faithfulness of $F$: the maps $n^k\pi \colon \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/(n^p-1)$ for $k \in \{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ are pairwise distinct, hence the same goes for the $n^k_*\pi_*$. We conclude that $F(\mathbf Z)_\mathbf Q$ cannot have finite length as $\mathbf Q[x]$-module, so $F(\mathbf Z)$ has infinite rank. $\square$

Comment: When considering this question the other day, I had convinced myself there was an obstacle to approaches like this one, and I don’t see how this answer gets around the obstacle (though I don’t see any flaw in your argument either).  The obstacle is this: It seems that after the use of Lemma 2, the proof only uses the value of $F$ on cyclic groups.  But if I’m not mistaken, there *is* a functor defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ and all finite groups giving a faithful f.g. projective cover (details in next comment).  So any answer must use values of $F$ on non-cyclic infinite groups.

Comment: The functor is given as follows: For finite $A$, take $F(A)$ to be free on the set $A \setminus \{0\}$; this is easily seen to be a functorial f.g. projective cover.  Take $F(\mathbb{Z})$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$ with the identity cover.  The action on maps to/from $\mathbb{Z}$ is “the first thing you guess” in each case; checking functoriality has to work by cases depending whether the source/target of maps are $\mathbb{Z}$ or finite, but all cases work out, essentially since there are no nonzero maps from finite groups to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Am I mistaken, or does your answer get around this somehow?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I don't see how you get a functor, but maybe "the first thing I guess" is not what you thought would be!. If you take the map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by multiplication by $2n$ and the nonzero map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the composition is zero, independently of $n$. How do you define the functor on these maps?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I also do not understand the action of $F$ on maps between finite groups. If $A$ and $B$ are finite and $f \colon A \to B$, the only obvious candidate for $F(f)$ would send the generator $a \in F(A)$ to the generator $f(a) \in F(B)$, but that is not additive

Comment: @AndreaFerretti I thought we didn't want $F$ to be additive?

Comment: $F$ does not need to be additive, but $F(f)$ had better be a homomorphism

Comment: @AndreaFerretti I don't think being a homomorphism is a problem: we're just defining a map between free abelian groups by saying where a basis gets sent. But there is a problem: what happens if $f(a) = 0$?

Comment: You are right, and I agree that $f(a) = 0$ is an issue, but then one could just take the free group over $A$. Your previous example of composing with a map from $\mathbb{Z}$ is where functoriality seems to fail

Comment: @JeremyRickard: You’re right, that functoriality case (with the maps from $\mathbb{Z}$) does fail — I’d been sloppy in thinking it through!  So the “obstacle” is not a problem; sorry for the noise.  (The action on finite groups does work fine, though, that I did check carefully: it’s perhaps clearer if you present $F(A)$ as $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A}/(e_0)$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus (A \setminus \{0\})}$.  The reason for killing $e_0$, not just using $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A}$, was because I thought that would allow the functor to be extended to a fin. gen. value on $\mathbb{Z}$.)